# How to specify the type of a given interface with generics?

Tags: java, generics

Given this set of `interfaces`:

```
interface BaseView {

}

interface UserView extends BaseView {
    void showMe(User user);
}

interface Presenter {
    void attachView(BaseView view);
}

interface UserPresenter extends Presenter {
    void logout();
}
```

I've created an `abstract class` which will be use it as a base clase foundation.  And I’m trying to define in this class with generics the type of the `interface` that will be implemented by the subclass. Something like this:

```
public abstract class Screen<P extends Presenter, V extends BaseView> implements V {
    private final P presenter;

    public Screen(P presenter) {
        this.presenter = presenter;
        this.presenter.attachView(this);
    }
}
```

That way, a subclass could be defined as follows:

```
public class UserScreen extends Screen<UserPresenter, UserView> {

    @Override showMe(User user) {

    }

    private void clickButtonLogout() {
        presenter.logout();
    }
}
```

Well, that's what I want to achieve it. But this line does not compile:

```
public abstract class Screen<P extends Presenter, V extends BaseView> implements V
```

> Error: Interface expected here

By "here", the compiler means the generic type V.

So, is there a way to specify the type of the interface which will be implememted by the subclass with generics?

Comment: No. You cannot `implements T` with a generic. Generics are compile time type checks anyway.

Comment: No, there isn't a way to do this.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch In *Java* they are compile time mostly. Lack of reification mostly due to Java's use of erasure for implementation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Any thoughts about how to achieve this kind of design with another legal approach?

Comment: I don't see the problem. If you want UserScreen to implement UserView, why can't you put `implements UserView`?

Comment: Because I would like this base class will be as much explicit as possible about what types the subclass need to implement. Plus, if i do so, the base class could not be able any more to attach the view with the presenter, as it shown in the code provided  "this.presenter.attachView(this);"

Comment: You would be able to do `this.presenter.attachView(this)` if you made Screen implement BaseView.